# Adding features to existing layer through CSV file in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have an existing QGIS project that was prepared with the QGIS GUI application. It contains several layers, one which I need to update with pyQGIS. The project data is stored in an sqlite database. Since I inherited the project from my predecessor without proper handover, I have to do a lot of guess work on how things are set up. My plan is now to do the following:

1. Prepare CSV file with the relevant feature information
2. Remove existing features from the relevant layer (currently 526 features)
3. Add features from my CSV file to the layer (640 features to be added)

However steps 2 and 3 are going wrong. This is my code:

```
import os
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5.QtSvg import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import pandas as pd

print("loading map with projects...")
app = QgsApplication([], True) 
app.setPrefixPath(r"C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.10/apps/qgis", True) 
app.initQgis() 
Project = QgsProject.instance() 
Project.read("filename.qgz")

layers = Project.mapLayers()


print("updating projects in map...")

lay = layers["layername"] # choosing the relevant layer that needs updating

lay.startEditing()

fields = lay.fields()

print("number of features: {}".format(lay.featureCount()))

listOfIds = [feat.id() for feat in lay.getFeatures()]
lay.deleteFeatures( listOfIds )
print("Number of features to be removed: {}".format(len(listOfIds)))
print("number of features: {}".format(lay.featureCount()))

lay.triggerRepaint()
projects = pd.read_csv("projects.csv")

featureList = []
feature_names = ["pk","x","y", "ProjectName", "Category", "Capacity"]
for index, row in projects.iterrows():
    x,y = [row["x"],row["y"]]
    feature = QgsFeature(fields)
    geom = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(x, y))
    feature.setGeometry(geom)

    for f in feature_names:
        feature[f] = row[f]

lay.addFeatures(featureList)


lay.endEditCommand()
lay.triggerRepaint()

print("number of features: {}".format(lay.featureCount()))
```

I tried various alternative commands for updating the features. However when I render the map it is empty. Also when I open the updated project in the QGIS application it appears empty.

The code returns the following:

```
loading map with projects...
updating projects in map...
number of features: 526
Number of features to be removed: 526
number of features: 0
number of features: 0
```

So the layers are apparently not properly added. Also when running the code again, it again removes 526 features, despite deleting them in the previous run and adding 640 features. When opening the underlying SQLite database it seems that everything in there was updated properly.

How can I properly update the features in my layer, i.e. remove the old ones and add new ones?

Comment: Skimming through your code, you're mixing two types of editions: the one with `QgsVectorLayer` and the one with `QgsVectorDataProvider`. Stick to only one. Devs recommend the one from `QgsVectorLayer`. So, in an edit session do not call the data provider edit methods (like `lay.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature])`). I don't know if that solves your issue, but for sure will make your code cleaner and more predictable from now on.

Comment: Thanks @GermánCarrillo ,I changed the code accordingly and also edited my question. It did not solve the main problem, but at least now the results don't differ any more between different runs.